# Proving that a map formed by a closed curve is always 2-colorable

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I need to prove that a closed curve on the plane, which forms a map using its intersections with itself, forms a 2-colorable map. How to approach this problem? I'm thinking of proving that the graph of vertices is bipartite but can't find an appropriate bipartition.

Answer (score 1):

Use that every vertex is of even degree. And I suppose you want to colour the faces, not the vertices.

Comment: The question wants me to color the vertices.

Comment: @user54609. If that's really what the question asks, it's wrong. It's easy to find a closed curve in the plane with three intersections that form a triangle. Make a slightly extended common pretzel. If pretzels aren't part of your cultural background, I guess you'll you'll have to do a bit of research.

Comment: @user54609 coloring maps usually means coloring faces not vertices. When you color vertices it is irrelevant if the graph is planar or not ;)

Comment: Oh I see. Then coloring faces :). I vaguely remember a theorem stating the two are equivalent though...

Comment: Also, why is each vertex of even degree?

Answer (score 1):

The problem basically reduces to the following well known Theorem in graph theory:

A connected planar graph is Eulerian if and only if its dual $G^*$ is bipartite.

The proof is pretty obvious if you observe that the degree of a vertex in $G$ is equal to the number of edges of the corresponding face in $G^*$.